# modify projection layer for seq2seq in tensorflow - python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to modify the projection layer of my NMT (neural machine translation) model. I want to be able to update the number of units without reinitializing all of the weights. I followed the tutorial from the tensorflow NMT tutorial found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq). Here is the code for my decoder:

```
# Decoder
train_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
    decoder_cell, train_helper, decoder_initial_state)

maximum_iterations = tf.round(tf.reduce_max(encoder_input_lengths) * 2)

# Dynamic decoding
train_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(train_decoder)

# Projection layer -- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO MODIFY
projection_layer = layers_core.Dense(
    len(language_base.vocabulary), use_bias=False)

train_logits = projection_layer(train_outputs.rnn_output)

train_crossent = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=decoder_outputs, logits=train_logits)

# Target weights
target_weights = tf.sequence_mask(
    decoder_input_lengths, params.tgt_max_len, dtype=train_logits.dtype)
target_weights = tf.transpose(target_weights)

# Loss function
train_loss = (tf.reduce_sum(train_crossent * target_weights) /
    tf.to_float(params.batch_size))

# Calculate and clip gradients
train_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
gradients = tf.gradients(train_loss, train_vars)
clipped_gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(
    gradients, params.max_gradient_norm)

# Optimization
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(params.learning_rate)
update_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(
    zip(clipped_gradients, train_vars))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow doesn't really let you change the shape of a variable (which is related to the number of units here) without some effort.

Instead, you're better off preallocating a larger-than-usual number of units and masking the units you don't use to 0 during the early stages of training, and update your mask as you go (use a variable to store the mask to make updating it easier).

Comment: What would happen if I re-created the projection layer... Would that have an effect on the accuracy of my model... I am using a bidirectional dynamic encoder and a decoder as the core of the model... I am trying to make a chatbot

Comment: If you recreated the layer you'd have a small performance penalty and would have to manually copy the weights over.

Comment: I don’t mind the performance penalty... how would I copy over the weights?

Comment: You'd need to take the old ones, concat something to them, and assign the result to the new ones.

Comment: If I create a new layer, and then copy over the weights, how can I delete the old ones?

Comment: They will leak; it's part of the performance penalty you'll pay with this approach.